# Can't stablish SMTP connection with Yahoo, I think the TCP handshake is failing

Tags: email, networking, tcp, smtp, handshake

I'm trying to stablish a SMTP connection with hotmail or yahoo (both giving the same issue). They connect to my server (192.168.1.220) on port 25 and I send the 220 confirmation, but they don't reply with HELO, EHLO nor anything.

So I scanned the packages and I found this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj4r0.jpg

As far as I see, SYN is sent without any problems, SYN-ACK works right, then ACK doesn't reply with the right Seq value (it should be 2, right?).

Do you know what could be causing the connection issue? Should I try UDP or nothing here is wrong and I am misunderstanding the whole situation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't here.

We were sending our 220 message just with \n and no \r. So we sent "220 Hello\n\r" and it worked.